# Combine multiple if else statement

Tags: python, if-statement

I have made a functionality wherein if the value of the commodity increase by 1 percent the threshold value also increases by 1 percent. The best case here would be to use switch statement in python. But there are none in python as mentioned at [Replacements for switch statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python)

Hence I used multiple if else and elif statements in python.

code:

```
price = 100.0

Price=104

threshold=90.0

if Price == 1.01*price:
    threshold=1.01*threshold

elif Price == 1.02*price:
    threshold=1.02*threshold

elif Price==1.03*price:
    threshold=1.03*threshold

else:
    threshold=1.04*threshold
```

Here:

- price = initial price of commodity
- Price = price after we buy quantity. Keeps changing every min
- Threshold = minimum price which the commodity can reach. If the price of the commodity goes below this threshold we sell the commodity.

What I mean to attain by implementing this functionality is that a unit percent increase in the Price of the commodity should increase the threshold by same unit percent.Nothing should be done to the threshold if the Price of the commodity goes below the original buyprice.

Hence when the price of the commodity goes to 101 which is 1 percent increase in the price of the commodity the threshold also increases by same amount. if the Price of the commodity increases to 2 percent the threshold also increases by 2 percent of original threshold value 2 percent increase in 90 is 91.8 If the buyprice decreases by 1 percent that is becomes 99 the threshold stays same that is 90. If the price goes on decreasing and goes below threshold we sell commodity.

Now

Hence the output I get by above programme is:

```
price   Price   Threshold
100     101     90.9
100     102     91.8
100     103     92.7
100     104     93.6
100.    99.     90
100.    96      90
100.    91.     90
```

Do note that this is just an example shown. In real Scenario the Price value gets updated every 1 second

My question is I use multiple if and elif statements in the programme. So is there a way to combine these multiple if and elif statements so as to make the code shorter and cover all the scenarios?

Comment: do you just want to iterate it by `0.01` higher each time? What's the max value? (of your `1.01` multiplier

Comment: Your code and your "output" don't seem to match. You code says that if `Price == x*price`, then you set `threshold` to `x*price`, but your output always has `Threshold` less than `price`

Comment: Yes I want to iterate it by 1 percent everytime until price increases by 5 percent or is equal to 105 in this case

Comment: And what about `threshold *= Price/price`? As a side note, capitalized names are usually reserved for classes in Python , and having two variables that only differ by capitalization is not very explicit and is rather error prone...

Comment: @quamrana changed the code. That was because threshold =90 not 100

Comment: Your last comment contradicts the explanation in your question and your current code - or there is something I don't understand in it. What about this 5 percents??

Comment: Setting `threshold =90` does nothing. Your `if/elif` just reset `threshold= ...` later.

Comment: @ ThieryLathuille I did not get you

Comment: @quamrana the output and code match I have personally tested using Price as 100,101,102,103,104

Comment: I'm sorry, but you can't flat out contradict people who are helping you. You've got to realise that we make comments in order to help you.

Comment: You need to be very careful with code like this due to the vagaries of floating point arithmetic. For example, in Python the assertion that 103.26 * 1.01 == 104.2926 will fail. Therefore your tests should be based on low tolerance ranges

Comment: When I run your code as it is now, it falls into the final `else:` and I get `price,Price,threshold` as `100 103.26 104.0`

Comment: @quamrana I did not mean to do that. Apologies If I have done so

Comment: Ok, thanks. Do you see why we don't understand what you are saying?

Comment: @quamrana I did. I will reproduce the code and try to post the edited one

Comment: @quamrana I have updated the code to match ouput exactly as shown

Comment: Ok, that's much more clear.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind to upgrade your pyhon, in python 3.10 they have incorporated switch-case pattern matching. https://docs.python.org/3.10/whatsnew/3.10.html

However, I would use a loop for that and use more abstract coding for that purpose.

```
if Price == (1+increase)*price:
    threshold = (1+increase)*price
```

Where increase is that percentage that you want to add to your Price. Given that increase you can just check when the price has risen to that increment and update threshold.

Another way would be to just

```
increase= Price/price
```

However, I have not tested it so give it a try! ;)

Comment: tried your solution. The issue being the threshold remains same whatever I change the Price to

Comment: What do you specifically want to change or what is your input? price? increment? give me more info

Comment: added additional information related to the variables of the programme